# Find WEKA attributes class names for option handling

Tags: java, data-mining, weka

I'm currently writing a new filter in WEKA. Before applying this filter on a read dataset a few options should be possible to be set. One of them should be the attributes class name. Now the answer is, which variable gives me access to the read dataset BEFORE my processing method which is called when applying the filter??

It seems that there has to be an Instances variable with all the information because the WEKA explorer shows all the different classes after opening the file.

Answer (score 2):

First you must load (or create) a set of instances.  If you have an ".arrf" file saved you can load instances as follows:

```
// initialize source
DataSource source=null;
Instances originalTrain=null;
String rootPath="/some/location/filename.arff" //the location and name of your data
source = new DataSource(rootPath);
originalTrain = source.getDataSet();  //originalTrain is an Instance object with your data
```

Now, if I understand what you are looking for, this information can be accessed by looking at the Attribute class.

```
Instances originalTrain=//load the training data  

//find the name of the first attribute
String name=originalTrain.attribute(0).name(); 
System.out.println(name); //look at new name
```

You can learn more about the Attribute class and these different functions by looking at the [JavaDoc](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/ml_docs/weka/weka.core.Attribute.html)

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where I get the instances object from to access the attributes. The first time my code produces an Instances object is when applying the filter. But somewhere before the input seems to be saved in an other Instances object. And this is what I'm searching for.
I followed this description to write the new filter. And it does not include specific loading of the data set. http://weka.wikispaces.com/Writing+your+own+Filter+%28post+3.5.3%29

Comment: I updated to include how to load a dataset...is this what you mean?

Comment: Is there a way to get all of the attribute names without knowing how many there are?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could maybe use a for loop where you query the number of attributes with originalTrain.numAttributes()?  http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Instances.html#numAttributes--